# Why do I need to use a Lambda expression here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Grid.razor:

```
@foreach (var row in Rows)
{
    <tr @onclick="@(() => OnRowClick(row))">
        @GridBody(row)
    </tr>
}
```

Grid.razor.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Web.Components.Grid
{

    public class GridRow<TItem>
    {
        public TItem Item { get; set; } = default!;
        public int Id { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool Active = false;
    }

    public partial class Grid<TItem>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 100;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment GridHeader { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<GridRow<TItem>> GridBody { get; set; } = default!;


        public async Task OnRowClick(GridRow<TItem> row)
        {
            //...        
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected.  However the following line of code in Grid.razor is not clear to me:

```
<tr @onclick="@(() => OnRowClick(row))">
```

The above works, but initially I had attempted the following:

```
<tr @onclick="@(OnRowClick(row))">
```

Without the lambda expression the compiler produces the following error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'
```

Why is a lamda function necessay here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `OnRowClick(row)`, you're directly invoking the `OnRowClick` function and assigning the result to `onclick`. Using `() => OnRowClick(row)` is assigning the lambda function to `onclick`, such that it can be called later (thus calling `OnRowClick`).

Thinking of `onclick` as a variable, here's the difference you'd see in C#:

```
Task<SomeType> onclick = OnRowClick(row); // Invoked now, onclick contains the result
```

vs.

```
Func<Task<SomeType>> onclick = () => OnRowClick(row); // Can be invoked later
```

You could shorthand things if `row` wasn't required as a parameter, e.g. `@onclick=@OnRowClick`, since you'd be passing a function that can be invoked later instead of invoking it now.